# Why does it prints 12 instead of 10 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, assignment-operator

Every time I try this the console log prints 12 instead of 10:

```js
let number1 = 3;
let number2 = 2;
number1 += number2;
number2 += number1;
let result = number1 + number2;
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Why do you expect 10 as the result? Can you write down the steps?

Comment: Why do you think it should print 10? You effectively sum two copies of `3` and three copies of `2`, that totals 12...

Comment: `number1 += number2` => `number1 = 5`. `number2 += number1` => `number2 = 7`. `result = 5 + 7 = 12`.

Comment: The reason you get 12 as a result is because you are using += to reassign the values back to themselves. Here is the breakdown.


 1. let number1 = 3 and let number2 = 2
 2. We add them in the first step, number1 += number2, this means 3 + 2 is now equal to number1 (number1 is now 5)
 3. number2 += number1 , so number2 is still 2 and number1 is 5. 5 + 2 = 7 and 7 is now the new value of number2.
 4. Finally, in let result = number1 + number2, we are adding 5 and 7 to get 12.

Essentially, the code is doing exactly what you told it to do.

Comment: It's 12 because in the line `number2 += number1;` the `number1` *already* includes number2 from the line above.

Answer (score 4):

```
let number1 = 3; 
let number2 = 2; 

number1 += number2;
// number1 = 3 + 2 = 5; 

number2 += number1;
// number2 = 2 + 5 = 7; 

let result = number1 + number2;
// result = 5 + 7 = 12;
 
console.log(result);
```

Why should the result be 10?